# Mail Sender And Subject Character Encoding With Persits

Tags: android, email, asp-classic

I have a system working with Persits Mail. Accualy all mails sending correctly but only android native mail application not showing turkish characters in subject and sender text. I am sharing images and mail send code below.

Mail send Function

```
Sub sendIt(Mesaj,Subjectt,Senderr,sMail,mHost,mFrom,mUsername,mPasword)
    Posta = trim(Posta)
    Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
    Mail.Charset = "ISO-8859-9"
    Mail.Host       = mHost
    Mail.From       = mFrom
    Mail.Username   = mUsername
    Mail.Password   = mPasword
    Mail.FromName   = Senderr
    Mail.AddAddress sMail
    Mail.Subject    = Subject
    Mail.IsHTML     = True
    Mail.Body       = Mesaj
    Mail.Send
End Sub
```

Android Native Mail App Screenshot (Problem is here)
[image: It must be "Araştırma Anketi"]

Gmail Mail App Screenshot (Sender and Subject has Turkish Chars Correctly)
[image: On gmail app it's all true]

Comment: I don't know anything about Android, but these days utf-8, which is a universal character set, is the standard rather than the language specific ISO sets, and you may have more luck with it

Comment: @John if you can advise me for persist mail encoding maybe i can find a solution about this problem. Not need to know android in this situation i think. I have to set persist mail subject, sender encoding. Thanks for comment.

Comment: In your code sample I'd use `Mail.Charset = "utf-8"`.  Aside from that I recommend the steps in this post where relevant. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An email message field to be sent in header (to, from, subject and other standard and custom headers) must be encoded when it contains non-ASCII characters.

AspEmail has a helper method [EncodeHeader](http://www.aspemail.com/manual_object.html#EncodeHeader) to encode such fieds, so you can use it.

In the given example code, `FromName` and `Subject` must be encoded.

```vb
Sub sendIt(Mesaj,Subjectt,Senderr,sMail,mHost,mFrom,mUsername,mPasword)
    Posta = trim(Posta)
    Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
    Mail.Charset = "ISO-8859-9"
    Mail.Host       = mHost
    Mail.From       = mFrom
    Mail.Username   = mUsername
    Mail.Password   = mPasword
    Mail.FromName   = Mail.EncodeHeader(Senderr, "ISO-8859-9")
    Mail.AddAddress sMail
    Mail.Subject    = Mail.EncodeHeader(Subject, "ISO-8859-9")
    Mail.IsHTML     = True
    Mail.Body       = Mesaj
    Mail.Send
End Sub
```

---

[AspEmail Object Reference](http://www.aspemail.com/manual_object.html#EncodeHeader)

> *`Function EncodeHeader(Header As String, Optional Charset = "ISO-8859-1") As String`*
>
> Encodes a string containing non-US-ASCII characters according to
>   RFC-1522, returns the resultant encoded string. Use this method to
>   encode a non-US-ASCII subject, sender's name or recipient's name, e.g.
>
> `Mail.Subject = Mail.EncodeHeader("La fête à Jean-Sébastien Bach")`
>
> or
>
> `Mail.AddAddress "oystein@somecompany.no", Mail.EncodeHeader("Øystein")`
>
> Charset can be set to "UTF-8" or any valid character set code
>   described in [Chapter 6](http://www.aspemail.com/manual_06.html).

Comment: @EmreErol glad to help. Bu ne hız bu arada :)

Comment: Ya ben problemi çözdüm aslında buraya da yazacaktımda kendi sorumu kendim cevaplamayayım, puan kazanmaya çalışıyor derler diye yazmadım :) telefonda elimdeydi, bildirim gelince en azından teşekkür edeyim dedim sağolasın :)

Comment: @EmreErol it's allowed to answer your own question and accept it in SO. / Hiç sorun olmaz yapabilirsin hocam. Rica ederim, kolay gelsin.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin - Is there anything similar I need to do if I'm using CDOSYS?

Comment: @John No you don't. CDO will encode those fields implicitly by consuming the specified charset of `objEmail.BodyPart.Charset`